# Substitute value in an algebraic expression

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)=-x^4 - x^2 +7x + x^2$

I have been told to find $p(-2)$. 
How do I go about doing that? 
Will it be -
$$-(-2)^4 -(-2)^2 + 7(-2) +(-2)^2 = -30$$ 
Or - 
$$ 2^4+ 2^2 + 7(-2) +(-2^2) = 10 $$
I'm pretty confused about this right now.

Comment: For example, $-x^4$ is the negative of $x^4$. So at $x=-2$ it has value $-(-2)^4$. This is $-16$. The way you use parentheses is non-standard, and can be a source of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be neither of those, actually. Every place you see an $x,$ you'll want to write $(-2),$ instead, so you have $$p(-2)=-(-2)^4-(-2)^2+7(-2)+(-2)^2=-16-4-14+4=-30.$$ Your first line is incorrect. $$-(-2^4)-(-2^2)+7(-2)+(-2^2)=-(-16)-(-4)-14+(-4)=16+4-14-4=2.$$ Be careful with the order of operations.

Comment: It appears to me that the first line is incorrect because of notation, the correct value indicating that the correct calculation was probably the intended meaning.  Nonetheless, the incorrect notation is important to fix, and e.g. $(-2^4)\neq (-2)^4$.  To Mayank: remember that $-a^2$ means the same thing as $-(a^2)$, the negation of the square of $a$, whereas $(-a)^2$ is needed for the square of $-a$.  (And similarly for other powers.)

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for clearing that, the first line was typed in a hurry so I didn't check the notation.

Answer (score 3):

$$p(-2) = -(-2)^4-(-2)^2 + 7(-2) + (-2)^2 = -16 - 4 - 14 + 4 = -30$$

Comment: Nicely done! +1

Answer (score 1):

$p(x)=7x-x^4=7(-2)-(-2)^4=-14-16=-30$

(see that both $x^2$ in $p(x)$ cancel each other so $p(x)=7x-x^4$)

Comment: What's the point of 2 brackets?